# How to pass a variable in a curl command

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, curl, groovy

I have a below variable :

```
echo "${payload}"
```

Output of Veriable is :

```
\"G1/H77/J1\",\"G1/H77/J2\",\"G1/H77/J3\",\"G10/H77/J1\",\"G10/H77/J2\"
```

Now, I have to pass this values to curl POST request :

```
def VALUES_BEFORE = sh(script: 'curl -X POST "http://kub01.abc.com:345678/abc/def" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{\"cell_ids\": ["${payload}"]}\' | json_pp',returnStdout: true).trim()
```

But, Curl command not taking this variable and I am unable to get the proper output.

**Is it the correct method I am using to pass the variable as a data to curl command?**

Your help would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Use a real JSON mangler like `jq` or whatever function your language provides.

Comment: guess: try to put that payload out of single quotes `'... "${payload}" ...'` -> `'... '"${payload}"' ...'`

Comment: Just make the main quotes doubled ""

Comment: Is `payload` an environment variable or just a shell variable? Perhaps you better show the definition of the variable.

Comment: #1 Is your `\"G1/H77/J1\",\"G1/...` is a raw string to be used as a field in a valid json? #2 How do you know the curl is not taking the variable? Do you have a backend log of http controller /abc/def ?

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

If you want to use a groovy variable inside of string, you need to use double quotes. And if you need  double quotes inside of string, escape them.

```
def foo = "im a double quote \" inside of double quoted string"
```

Also if you need to use $

```
echo("This is a literal dollar sign: \$")
```

If you use single quotes, the variable is not evaluated.

I tried your code and a webhooks tester. As expected the sent json was:

[image]

## Fix #1

Escape $ sometimes is a pain, so it's not optimal but it works just concatenate values like

`"hi " + variable`

In your case

```
script: "curl .. -d '{\"cell_ids\": ["+payload+"]}'"
```

**full pipeline here**

```
pipeline{
    
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    def payload = "\"G1/H77/J1\",\"G1/H77/J2\",\"G1/H77/J3\",\"G10/H77/J1\",\"G10/H77/J2\""
                    def output = sh(script: "curl -X POST 'https://webhook.site/dac07d08-3d99-4a71-8170-f1529c7ff550' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"cell_ids\": ["+payload+"]}'" ,  returnStdout: true).trim()
                    println output
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

So the body sent to the http endpoint is the expected

[image]

## References

- https://webhook.site  (to test http invocations)
- hot to escape a $ https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17067/15159